# Bootstrap Image in same line

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, kendo-ui

I want to place an image (info icon) on the same line to the right of this drop down, with the below code the button appears on a new line?

```
 <div class="form-group">

                        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="insur1">Insurance</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                                .Name("insurance")
                                .DataTextField("Text")
                                .DataValueField("Value")
                                .Value("Yes")
                                .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
                                      new SelectListItem() {
                                          Text = "Yes",
                                          Value = "true"
                                      },
                                      new SelectListItem() {
                                          Text = "No",
                                          Value = "false"
                                      }
                                  })
                            )

                        </div>
                        <img style="float:right" src="~/Images/info.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Info">
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
 <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="insur1">
            Insurance</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
            <select style="float: left;">
                <option>asdf</option>
                <option>asdf</option>
                <option>asdf</option>
            </select>
            <img style="float: left" src="/Images/small.png" class="img-responsive" width="20"
                height="20" alt="Info">
        </div>
    </div>
```